# How to do if customer wants to specify his key for exporting project to .apk?

Tags: android, export, key, apk

I am writing a [Swing app](http://code.google.com/p/apk-signer/) by NetBeans.

My customer wants to sign the .apk by his own key. How can I do that in a convenient way? Assuming the customer does not know anything about Eclipse IDE or the console. And we are in different countries (I mean I can't go there to help him export project from Eclipse/ or sign the .apk from console).

Thank you in advance if you're going to improve the project  :-)

Comment: Can't he send you the key and let you sign it?

Comment: @Jivings, he can. But I need to know the passphrase, while he doesn't want that.

Comment: Customers are annoying aren't they?

Comment: Annoying me? No, I'll do anything for customers :-) Maybe I'll end up with writing small Swing app to let him sign the .apk.

Comment: There's already a tool. See my answer.

Comment: **Edited**: I made a Swing app which calls `keytool` and `jarsigner`. The only problem is you need to ask customer to download and install JDK. But it seems this is not big problem. If anyone likes, ping me a message and I'll give you the code (not sure if my code is useful, or useless to you :-)

Comment: I'm interested if you're going to distribute!

Comment: Hi Jivings, it's here: http://code.google.com/p/apk-signer/ I hope it's useful for you  :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a tool that allows as easy way for non-developers to sign apps](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=997180). Point him at that, it has a nice simple GUI that he should be able to manage.

Comment: Thank you, but if you could do these suggestions, then it would be brilliant: **1)** let the user create his key file, he can set his own passphrase for the file, can create alias name and set passphrase for alias; and in the future the user can use his key to sign the new version .apk. **2)** open source the project. If you open the project, it would be the key to let the user trust your code. Thanks again, Jivings  :-)

Comment: Its not my code, but I'll consider writing one if nothing else crops up.